# Ударение в слове "первообразная"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как ставить ударение в слове "первообразная"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь "плавающее" ударение, хотя, по логике, правильнее "первоОбразная" - от слова "***о***браз".

Answer (score 2):

В затруднительных случаях лучше проверять ударение по словарю. Данное слово можно найти в словаре А.Зализняка:

> первообра'зный, первообра'зная, первообра'зное...

Answer (score 1):

Однозначное ударение: первообрАзная (во всех словарях так)